# Search engine with oracle database table

Tags: sql, oracle, full-text-search, search-engine

I am working on implementing following search capabilities with oracle database.

I have one table with 80+ columns having approx 90k records. Possible of 4k records addition every year. On and average 500 to 1000 insert and update during day.

There are 15+ core fields for which user can perform any of following type of search. User can select one or all 15 core fields to specify what all fields we need to consider for search.

3 types of search:

1. User entered value is compared with column value using = to operator. Case sensitive exact search
2. User entered value is lowered first. Remove all special characters from it. Supply that value for comparison. The similar process i.e. lower case and special characters removal will needs to happen first for column values and then use = operator for user provided value comparison. Case insensitive and exact value search
3. Remove all space, special characters from user provided value as well as database table columns value and then look for user provided value using contains kind of search.

I have intermittent knowledge of query building and underlying index requirement for faster execution. I have also started exploring "oracle full text search (Oracle text)" capabilities.

My question is what is the best way to implement this kind of search capability. Is there any way over where I can use oracle full text search along with removal of special characters at database layer before comparison?